# Skype shows a blank window on the webcam part what could be the problem?

Tags: webcam, skype, cheese

The other party is sending their webcam view and I am sending mine, so that they can see everything fine, but i only can see a blank window.

when enabling the "show my webcam" it shows for a few milliseconds but then just disappears.
It happens with two different graphic cards, it's very unlikely to be graphics card related.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: Problems with skype itself ???

Comment: @Luciano: How enlightened, can you add some constructive comment ? Are you familiar with such problem? Can you suggest a workaround ? Thanks

Comment: Using other applications such as "cheese" it works?

Comment: Using cheese works, but please note that remote webcam image is not displayed either, is not really a webcam related issue.

Comment: That problem happens always with all your skype's contacts or just one ?

Comment: Just tried with one contact, but I don't think it's contact related, my own webcam image does not show either.

Comment: use ekiga because skype for linux is dead.

Comment: why is it dead? does ekiga allow me to call my other skype contacts?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember skype has a problem with v4l2 (video for linux 2) and has to use vl41 instead but it doesn't know were it is the solution was to shutdown skype then create a script. In a terminal type or paste

```
gksudo gedit /usr/local/bin/skype
```

and add these lines for a 32bit system

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

or these lines for a 64bit system

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

then type or paste this line in the terminal which will make the script executable

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/skype
```

after this you can open Skype and check in options/video devices and hit the test button.
this should make it possible to see your own webcam and others in skype.

Hope this helps.